# Save some pages from some Excel sheets as PDF

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following code to print a range of pages from a selection of sheets. I know that I could use a "print to PDF" printer to get the data to PDF. But when I print, some aspects of my Excel document don't turn out so pretty. However when I save as PDF, the document does become pretty. So I wonder if there is there any way to SAVE a range of pages from a selection of sheets AS PDF.

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "C").Value) Then 'Printa alla sidor
    Call Sheets(Cells(i, "A").Value).PrintOut
ElseIf Cells(i, "C").Value = 0 Then 'Printa fram till viss sida
    Call Sheets(Cells(i, "A").Value).PrintOut(1, 1)
ElseIf Cells(i, "C").Value > 0 Then 'Printa fram till viss sida
    Call Sheets(Cells(i, "A").Value).PrintOut(1, Cells(i, "C").Value)
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a possibility to use `.ExportAsFixedFormat method` according to [THIS MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836441%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

The most simple example of how to use this method presents the next line of code:

```
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "testFile.pdf"
```

where selected range is exported to PDF File called 'TestFile.pdf'

**Can I export multiple selections to the same PDF file?**

Yes, you can. There are two options available:

1. to export some non-continuous ranges from one sheet- use `Union()` which will make new page for each range inside:

   ```
   Union(Range("A1:f10"), Range("A15:d15")).ExportAsFixedFormat _
       xlTypePDF, "testFile.pdf"
   ```
2. to export ranges from different sheets- use `.ExportAsFixedFormat` as `Workbook method` which will export each printing area in the whole workbook to one PDF document. It goes in this way:

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "testFile2.pdf"
   ```

For second idea check additional parameters of `.ExportAsFixedFormat method` to limit pages to be printed.

Comment: Can I export multiple selections to the same PDF file? Say I want to export pages 1-2 from Sheet "A" and all pages from Sheet "B"?

Comment: see two additional options in my answer.

Comment: I still don't understand how to export pages 1-2 from Sheet "A" and all pages from Sheet "B"? Is it perhaps possible to export fro one sheet to PDF and then append from the other sheets?

Comment: the only way I can think of when using `.ExportAsFixedFormat` is to hide all rows/columns which you don't want to print out. After that you will need to ran 2nd solution from my answer.